# selected option value in php variable without form tag

Tags: php, html, cart

I made a cart system in which quantity is getting updated successfully but now i have added two new fields i.e color and size. I want to pass selected values in php variables.I don't want to use `<form>` tag.Is it possible to do so? I have tried following code. Any suggestions please.

**code**

```
<?php
$size = $_REQUEST['size'];//selected size
$color = $_REQUEST['color'];//selected color

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){
    $id=intval($_GET['id']);
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])){
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['size'];//session for size
        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['color'];//session for color
    }else{
       $sql_p="SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid={$id}";

        $query_p=mysqli_query($con, $sql_p);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query_p)!=0){
            $row_p=mysqli_fetch_array($query_p);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row_p['productid']]=array("quantity" => 1, "price" => $row_p['product_price'],"color"=>$color,"size"=>$size);
        }else{
            $message="Product ID is invalid";
        }
    }
}
?>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>

        <th>color</th>
        <th>size</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products where cat_id=2 ORDER BY product_name ASC");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
            <td><img src="images/<?php echo $row['product_image']; ?>" width="120px" height="120px"></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['product_desc']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "$" . $row['product_price']; ?></td>

            <td>Colors:
                <select name="color">
                    <option selected value="choose">choose</option>
                    <option value="blue" id="blue">Blue</option>
                    <option value="yellow" id="yellow">Yellow</option>
                    <option value="green" id="green">Green</option>
                </select></td>
            <td> <select name="size"><option selected value="Choose size">Choose</option>
                    <option value="XL" id="XL">XL</option>
                    <option value="L" id="L">L</option>
                    <option value="S" id="S">S</option></select>
            </td>

            <td><a href="index.php?page=women&action=add&id=<?php echo $row['productid']; ?> ">Add to Cart</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Color is a selection. Where do you want to make the selection if you don't use a form? How does PHP know?

Comment: @GolezTrol iwant both of my selections in a variable to use them at the top of the code in an array

Comment: Still not clear what you mean, sorry.

Comment: @GolezTrol i am trying to say that i want both of my selections to be added in my cart without form action. It should pass as a php variable when i click `add to cart` link.

Comment: I'd turn it around and make it an actual form. That way, you can select the product, the properties and use the submit button to add it to the cart. If you want to keep this link, you will need some javascript to add the properties to the link, but then you're basically recreating a poor man's form using a script and a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd turn it around and make it an actual form. That way, you can select the product, the properties and use the submit button to add it to the cart.

If you want to keep this link, you will need some Javascript to add the properties to the link, but then you're basically recreating a poor man's form using a script and a link.

Using an actual form per product, you can easily let the user select products and add them to the cart, without any need for scripts.

The script I added is just to show the url, since Stack Snippets doesn't make that very obvious.

```js
// Show the post url in the document, since forms are blocked in Stack Snippets.
$('form').on('submit', function() {
  document.write(
     'about to navigate to: ' + 
      $(this).attr('action') + '?' + 
      $(this).serialize());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="product" method="get" action="add.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="product" value="12345">
  <select name="color">
     <option value="red">red</option>
     <option value="green">red</option>
     <option value="blue">red</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do what you want using PHP alone. I think you are going to have to use a Browser side language like JavaScript.
Do you know you could use tables inside a form?

Comment: yes i know this. But i don't want to use any form here. I just want to pass selected color and size to ` $_SESSION['cart'][$row_p['productid']]=array("quantity" => 1, "price" => $row_p['product_price'],"color"=>$color,"size"=>$size)`